# Python Jinja2 typecast a string in listform from DB into a list

Tags: python, jinja2

I have an entry in my DB which is a string but it looks like a list:

```
["SomeText", "SomeValue", "SomeValue", "SomeValue", "SomeValue"]
```

It is type `text`

Now I want to iterate through the list in jinja2, but jinja2 recognizes this as a string, is there a way to typecast it into a list.

An alternative solution which I found would be to split the string so it becomes a list, I could already split the example above into the desired output with:

```
{% for item in db_item.db_column.split(",") %}
    <p> {{ item.replace('"', "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "") }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the output:

```
SomeText
SomeValue
SomeValue
SomeValue
SomeValue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by saving a splitable string to the DB.

```
information = Column(Text, nullable=False)
```

Data saved to `information` must be splitable on `:::`, example data:

```
SomeText:::SomeValue:::SomeValue:::SomeValue:::SomeValue
```

In jina2 I can split this string in view and iterate through the list:

```
{% for item in information.split(":::") %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the live result, the content of possible answers have been created this way:
https://www.path-of-exile-builds.com/quiz